# How can I customize the title text of the initial progress dialog in install4j?

Tags: install4j

The initial dialog with progress (Shows before the Welcome screen) has the text "Install4j Wizard" in the title bar.  Is there a way to customize the text in the title bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All messages in install4j can be customized by setting up a custom localization file on the "General Settings->Languages" step and overriding messages in the built-in editor. System messages can be listed with the "Override messages" tool bar button.

Answer (score 2):

There is a C:\Program Files\install4j5\resource\messages\ directory where are located default message for selected locales while installing. Edit the entry "PrepareInstaller" pleasure.

I hope this helps